# select columns with not null property

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am looking for a way to select columns with a not null property and store it on to an ArrayList.
I have searched many threads for an answer but no luck.

I created a function which allows me to read data from a table but the problem is I don't know how do I get it to read the column name with a not null property. Here is the code that I tried

```
Public Function getNull(ByVal table As String) As ArrayList
    Dim col_names As String = New String(getNames(table))
    Dim nullColumns As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    Dim dtreader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = withDatabase
    conn = New MySqlConnection(strConn)
    Try
        Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & table & " WHERE " & col_names & " IS NOT NULL", conn)
        conn.Open()
        dtreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dtreader.Read
           'Get column names with not null property'

        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " + ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
    Return nullColumns
End Function




Public Function getNames(ByVal table As String) As String
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim names As New String("")
    strConn = withDatabase
    conn = New MySqlConnection(strConn)
    Using conn
        conn.Open()
        Dim dt = conn.GetSchema("Columns", New String() {Nothing, Nothing, table})
        For Each row In dt.Rows
            names += row("COLUMN_NAME") + " AND "
        Next
        names = names.Remove(names.Length - 4)

    End Using
    conn.Close()
    Return names
End Function
```

The other threads I found was to find null values in a column, which is not I was looking for.

Comment: You write "WHERE * IS NOT NULL" - this is always true!

Comment: You cannot say `WHERE *` you have to specify a column name like `WHERE xxx IS NOT NULL AND yyy IS NOT NULL`